# Html <form> with php and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I would like to know in what way passing data from a form to a php file is best?

I have used ajax to retrieve a page and load into a div tag on the "master page", now there is a form on this sub page that needs to upload a file. So far i have got it to upload and the form posts to a new .php file where the data is handled.

When the data is handled and the page then navigates back to the master page, i noticed upon form submission when it is directed to the new php page, it shows blank white while the code executed and then redirects to the master page, my question is:

In order to eliminate the white page while code is being executed, is there a better way to go about this or is this sufficient and what can i do to not show the white page?

Thanks in advance.

Warren

Comment: You can post your form using ajax and then on success refresh page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply use jQuery. See how they interupt the submit and you may put validations etc. then process then do whatever you need: http://api.jquery.com/submit/

```
<form id="target" action="destination.html">
  <input type="text" value="Hello there">
  <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
<div id="other">
  Trigger the handler
</div>

$( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
  alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: So for this method the request for upload is sent to the php script but i stay on the page by interrupting it?

Comment: Yeah…  but you need to modify to upload it

Comment: Ah okay! Let me see if i have this correct. When i interrupt the submit, the document is still uploaded but stays on the current page so i can handle the uploaded document on the same page?

Answer (score 0):

You could use ajax to upload the files without submitting the form, for example by using a script like this :

http://www.a2zwebhelp.com/multiple-file-upload